# What does "A" represent? $A$ satisfies $xAx$; if $xAy$ and $yAx$, then $x=y$; if $xAy$ and $yAz$ then $xAz$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $E$ be a set and $x$, $y$, $z$ elements of $E$.
>
> Consider $A$ a certain object which satisfies the following :
>
> - $xAx$
> - If $xAy$ and $yAx$, then $x = y$.
> - If $xAy$ and $yAz$, then $xAz$.
>
> What is $A$?

Comment: $A$ looks like a relation. $xAy$ means $x$ is related to $y$.

Comment: Without more details (where the problem comes from, what topic, ...), this answer is near impossible to answer.

Comment: A good example is $A=\le$. So $x\le y,y\le x$ implies $x=y$ for real numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $A$ is a relation on the set $E$, i.e., $A\subseteq E\times E$.

Moreover, $(x,y)\in A$ is (for short) written as $xAy$

If $A$ satisfies all three conditions (reflexitivity, anti-symmetry, transitivity), then $A$ is an order relation.

Comment: It would be a *partial* order.

Answer (score 0):

I think that $A$ denotes an  relation on $E \times E$.

The first condition is reflexivity, the second anti - symmetry and the third transitivity.

Comment: Its not symmetry but anti-symmetry.

Comment: Ooops ! you are right !